# How to change a user value in Ruby & Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to set a user value (`two_weeks`) to `true` after an email has been sent to the user. This makes it so that the user never receives the same email twice. I'm having trouble successfully saving the user value, though, after the email is sent. This is the code in my `PagesController`:

```
def send_two_week
    user = Admin.find_chaps(User.all.where(two_week:"false"))
    UserMailer.two_week(user).deliver
    user.two_week = true
    user.save
    redirect_to "/admin"
end
```

The email does send, but the user's value `two_weeks` does not change. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try debugging the method. Place `binding.pry` before `user.save` and run the page. And in the console, check whether the values are updated and then execute `user.save`. See if it gets saved. Or you'll get the error which will help you debug. Try `user.errors` to see the error messages.Try using `user.save!` so that it'll the error if not successful.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks a bunch! Turns out I had other user values not related to that that prevented it from saving.

Answer (score 0):

Catch your exceptions by seeing in the console or put save! to through errors on save

The best way is you should always handle your exceptions.